# NPM - What's the difference between "<package>", "<package>-core", "<package>-loader", etc?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

For example, babel, babel-core, babel-loader...

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
  "webpack": "^3.10.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far an NPM is concerned, they are different packages with different names. In this case, you basically have 3 different packages from the babel developers, who have prefixed their packages with `babel-`.

**[babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel):**

A deprecated version of [babel-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-cli), a command line utility for using babel (`npm info babel` shows it is deprecated).

**[babel-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core):**

The core babel compiler library, a dependency of other babel packages.

**[babel-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader):**

A Webpack loader for transpiling babel code in Webpack.